# Sound and Video Skips on Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit

Tags: 11.10, sound, video, 64-bit

I preformed a dist-upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 and now I can not listen to any music or sounds (log on sound included), nor watch video without it stopping and then catching up and stopping again (This is flash or .mp4 through VLC).  I did not have this issue with 11.04 and have even just preformed a fresh install of my system.  I have tried to reinstall Pulse Audio and removing the .pulse folder but to no avail.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your first posting and include information about your sound- and graphics cards. You can find out their names by invoking lspci. If you are unsure include the complete output of lspci in your post.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem... It’s a known bug and there’s a easy fix for it as mentioned by virgil brumond on ubuntu bug report

open /etc/pulse/default.pa by issuing the command

```
sudo gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

and find the line:-  load-module module-udev-detect (Line 53 on my system. Yours will also be somewhere around that)

and change it to

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

save the file and reboot.